# Liquibase Gradle Plugin -> updateSQL command

Tags: liquibase, gradle-plugin

I have set up a gradle project that uses the Liquibase Gradle Plugin.

I am trying to use the functionality described in [liquibase output](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_output.html)

When I do gradle updateSQL basically the task outputs every change in the terminal (I try using this and putting the output of the command like "gradle updateSQL > changes.sql" but this also includes stuffs that I can not run later on, besides it haves all the changes and not just the updates).

I am trying to use the command updateCountSql ( the description says "Writes SQL to apply the next  change sets to STDOUT.") I have tried to enter parameters to this task but I can't make it work (constantly getting the error "The Liquibase updateCountSql command requires a value"), does anyone know how does it work?

I just need to keep track of the changes on the database, and be able to create a script with all the changes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm trying to accomplish the same.

Comment: We end up not using the plugin, it wasn't well supported, but I think your best changes to delete the rest of the output and extract the operations, or run the program directly without using gradle.

Answer (score 3):

You can use specify a target other than `stdout` using `outputFile`, e.g.:

```
liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            changeLogFile 'src/main/db/changelogs.groovy'
            url 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db'
            username 'myusername'
            password 'mypassword'
            outputFile 'path/to/script.sql'
        }
    }
}
```